# Best way of giving user's the ability to create their own datastores?

Tags: django, django-models

I want the user's of my site to be able to upload information into a database. I know that Django doesn't really allow me to let the user's have their own dynamically created tables. So I'm wondering what is the most efficient way of handling this.

For instance if all user's want to save mailing lists containing names, emails, numbers etc Would I just put all of these into one giant table with a column for the user ID or is there a smarter way to do this?

The basic functionality would allow users to upload data from a CSV in a restricted format. i.e. email, name which would be placed into a table like this:

---

### user  | email       | name

However, I'd like to further improve on this so that a user can specify their own fields. i.e. Add phone numbers, address or whatever other info they want. Perhaps also having the ability to add their own field headings under a model similar to the following.

---

### user | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4

Comment: This question is way too vague. Please edit your question and provide more detail about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a new table for each user. You would do exactly what you said, have a single mailing list table and store each record with an associated user ID. Then, when a user wants to view their lists, you filter that table by user ID. Similarly, if a user wanted to modify a mailing list, you'd make sure that user has the same ID as the record they're trying to modify.

Django already has a very powerful [user authentication and permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/) system. You should use it to ensure that only logged in users can access their records.

I suggest you take some time and carefully ready the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/) and follow the **First Steps** tutorials. They'll give you a better understanding about how to set up your models and implement authentication.